# Flex application not releasing video after playback

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, red5

I have a Flash Builder 4.6 program that plays multiple video files.  After each video plays, I want to release it.  If I use Process Explorer, I can still see that the videos are not released when they have finished playing.  This application is for training and one session may have upwards of 40 videos and about 1,800 people viewing a day.

I have the following to create and destroy the player.

```
hmpe = new VideoElement(new URLResource(src));
hostVideo.addMediaElement(hmpe);
hmp = new MediaPlayer();
hmp.play();
hmp.addEventListener(MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent.MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_CHANGE,MediaPlayerStateChange);
hmp.addEventListener(PlayEvent.PLAY_STATE_CHANGE, PlayStateChange);
hmp.addEventListener(TimeEvent.CURRENT_TIME_CHANGE, onTimeChange);
hmp.addEventListener(TimeEvent.COMPLETE,onTimeChange);
hmp.media = hmpe;

...
// To remove when stop is reached in PlayStateChange

hostVideo.removeMediaElement(hmpe);
hmpe = null;
hmp = new MediaPlayer();
```

Why is the file not released?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I did inside PlayStateChange, stop, to release the files.

```
                        hostVideo.removeMediaElement(hmpe);
                        hostVideo = new MediaContainer();
                        hmpe = null;
                        hmp.media = null;
                        hmp = new MediaPlayer();
```

Comment: I would assume that this causes the NetStream to close which would clear the video objects on the server side.